# Reducing memory footprint in anagram-finding program for text

Tags: c#, linq, memory-management

```
public static bool IsAnagramOf(this string word1, string word2)
{
    return word1.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(word2.OrderBy(x => x));
}

public static void Main()
  {
    Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(8192)));
    string test = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] split = test.Split(new Char[] { ',', '.', ' ' },
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
    {
        foreach (string s in split)
        {
            if (split[i] != s)
                if (split[i].IsAnagramOf(s))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);

                }
        }

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I really don't see how could this have too high memory footprint. I think you need to include some more details.

Answer (score 1):

and just shortening it up Jesse's answer...

```
private static bool IsAnagramOf(this string word1, string word2)
{
    return word1
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .SequenceEqual(word2.OrderBy(x => x));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var si = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(8192)))
    {
        Console.SetIn(si);
        var split = (Console.ReadLine() ?? "").Split(new[] {',', '.', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        split.SelectMany(t => split.Where(s => (t != s) && t.IsAnagramOf(s))).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);                
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what memory issue you're having with this, but there is a simpler way to write this, since you're already employing LINQ:

```
private static bool IsAnagramOf(this string word1, string word2)
{
    return word1
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .SequenceEqual(word2.OrderBy(x => x));
}

private static void Main()
{
    using (var si = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(8192)))
    {
        Console.SetIn(si);

        var test = Console.ReadLine();
        var split = test == null
            ? Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToArray()
            : test.Split(new[] { ',', '.', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var s in split.SelectMany(t => split.Where(s => (t != s) && t.IsAnagramOf(s))))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you please shed some light how using LINQ will be more beneficial than my code?

Comment: It's shorter, more concise, and indicates *intent* rather than the *way* to get to the results. Optimized LINQ libraries may also give you the memory and/or speed you are looking for. Measure early and often!